# Convex hull - Monotone chain algorithm error

Tags: javascript, python, 2d, polygon, convex-hull

I'm using the [Monotone chain algorithm](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Geometry/Convex_hull/Monotone_chain) to create a convex hull around a set of polygons. It works well sometimes, but on some shapes, it fails. Take a look at this example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfVJN.png

To the left is the shape *before* applying the algorithm, and to the right is *after*. There seems to be some minor calculation error somewhere, that I can't figure out.

Here is a link to my source-code (JavaScript): http://pastebin.com/GPVm9dQp

And here is the implementation in Python that I used as reference: http://pastebin.com/RgMKH3XN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without digging too deep into it, aren't you supposed to sort the list of points by x-position at some point?

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I just realized it! Thank you for letting us know :-)